# Jquery click function + css

Tags: jquery, css

i have no idea what i'm doing wrong. It's simple code, but doesn't work.

```
<div id="demo1" class="rating">
<input class="stars" type="radio" id="1" name="rating" value="1" />
<label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
</div>

<div id="demo2" class="rating2">
<input class="stars" type="radio" id="2" name="rating" value="1" />
<label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
</div>

  $(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#demo2 input.stars").click(function () {
                             alert('2');       
                        });

                        $("#demo1 input.stars").click(function () {
                              alert('1');        
                        });  
                    });
```

This code works fine (when i click first radio, it's alert "1", when click second it's alert "2").

But... with this CSS:

```
       <style>
        /****** Rating Starts *****/
        @import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

        fieldset, label, span { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        body{ margin: 20px; }
        h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

        .rating { 
            border: none;
            float: left;
        }

        .rating > input { display: none; } 

        .rating > label:before { 
            margin: 5px;
            font-size: 1.25em;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            display: inline-block;
            content: "\f005";
        }

                    .rating2 { 
            border: none;
            float: left;
        }


        .rating > label { 
            color: #ddd; 
            float: right; 
             cursor:pointer;
        }

        .rating2 > label { 
            color: #ddd; 
            float: right; 
             cursor:pointer;
        }





                    .rating2 > input { display: none; } 

        .rating2 > label:before { 
            margin: 5px;
            font-size: 1.25em;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            display: inline-block;
            content: "\f164";       
        }


    </style>
```

...with this css, i always get alert 1.

Help, please. No idea why when i click second radio i have alert 1 instead 2.

Regards
Luke

Comment: `.rating > input { display: none; }` and `.rating2 > input { display: none; } 
` will do it. Your rating inputs (which the click event is tied to) is not visible any more. Therefore, there's nothing on the page which will respond to your event.

Comment: Ok, inputs are invisible, but alert is shown, when i click each radio. Problem is, that with this css i get alert (1) no matter i click first or second radio.

Comment: The radios _are_ the inputs. Your statement makes no sense. And when I tried it, with the CSS, it didn't alert anything. Have suggested a solution below - your HTML could do with a tweak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.rating > input { display: none; }
```

and

```
.rating2 > input { display: none; }
```

are hiding the inputs which are the targets of your click event.

Your labels are not linked to the corresponding inputs. The `for` attribute of the label should hold the ID of the input that it corresponds to.

Therefore, change to:

```
<label class = "full" for="1" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
```

and

```
<label class = "full" for="2" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
```

Once you do that, the labels will also respond to the click event of the (hidden) input and display the correct value.

This fiddle demonstrates it *without* the CSS, showing just an empty radio button, which when clicked display the right values:

https://jsfiddle.net/qtu3x7sn/

This fiddle is the fixed version, with the labels correctly pointing to the relevant inputs, and the CSS included:

https://jsfiddle.net/qtu3x7sn/1/

Comment: Great! Thank You very much. So - my bad was, that i didn't understood FOR atribute in label.

Answer (score 2):

Font awesome icons are tied to `label:before` so you should do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#demo2 label").click(function() {
    alert('2');
  });

  $("#demo1 label").click(function() {
    alert('1');
  });
});
```

Full example here https://jsfiddle.net/496bgx53/

Update with input value https://jsfiddle.net/496bgx53/1/

Comment: @Aow, I would suggest that you simplify the css a bit

Comment: Ok, it works fine, but in jquery function i would like to get value of input.
I have ... rate:$(this).val() ...
So, when i change jquery to LABEL i can't get input value.

Comment: you could just find closest input value.. see updated answer